# Why aren't my applications appearing on my desktop?

Tags: appmenu

Apologies for the ignorance....
I'm transitioning as a longtime Windows user so this is very new for me. I recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my device and the only place I can find my applications are in show applications in the lower left-hand corner. I can see my favorites on the left, I can't seem to get my applications to populate on my desktop, how do I make this happen?

Comment: Press the Windows or Super Key and they should all popup on your screen.  Also install the `gnome-tweaks` that allow you to change things, as well as visit https://extensions.gnome.org/ where you can also get extensions turned on like menus, etc.

Comment: @Terrance I think the question is more about putting applications on the desktop than where to find them 

Comment: @matigo Indeed it is, but GNOME has that locked.  You can do it with the extensions, etc

Comment: What version and flavour are you using? "Latest version" is a bit ambiguous: there's two major types of Ubuntu releases. In most Linux desktops, it's not conventional to have application shortcuts on the desktop. This includes GNOME which is the default flavour of Ubuntu Desktop. What have you tried so far? Are there files under `~/Desktop` that you aren't actually seeing on the desktop? Do you really want all of your application shortcuts there? It might be worth mentioning that you can "Try Ubuntu" from any flavor's installation USB to get a feel for each flavour- they are all very different

Comment: Consider using Kubuntu or Ubuntu MATE, which provide a more traditional (Windows-like) experience.

Answer (score 0):

The Gnome Desktop, used by Ubuntu, moves away from a desktop that tends to be cluttered with icons and is covered most of the time. Applications thus are not dumped on your desktop by default. They only appear here if you put them there.

Still, again, that desktop is covered most of the time.

Instead arrange your applications in the application grid. That grid appears on a single click in the Dock, or on a single keypress, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Those five to 10 applications that you use all the time, put these on the Dock by making them favorites for immediate one click access.
You can also launch or switch to these favorites with the shortcut keys <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1/2/3/...</kbd>.